# Разделить цикл заголовками

Tags: wordpress

Есть цикл типа постов objects, которому присвоено произвольное поле select на выбор с двумя значениями 1:Квартиры 2:Дома
Сначала идут посты Квартиры потом Дома, нужно вставить заголовок перед началом постов с вариантом произвольного поля Квартиры и Дома соответственно. Как вариант разбивал на 2 запроса WP_Query, но тут нужно сохранить пагинацию.

```
<?php $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'objects',
   'posts_per_page' => 8,
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value',
   'meta_key' => 'comm_title'
);
$comm = new WP_Query($args);
if($comm->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while($comm->have_posts()): $comm->the_post();?>

     <span class="post"><?php the_title(); ?></span>

<?php endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); endif; ?>
```

Нужно получить:

```
<h3>Квартиры</h3>
<span class="post">Квартира 1</span>
<span class="post">Квартира 2</span>
<span class="post">Квартира 3</span>
<h3>Дома</h3>
<span class="post">Дом 1</span>
<span class="post">Дом 2</span>
<span class="post">Дом 3</span>
```

Comment: В WP_Query() надо сделать сортировку по мета-полю https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-proizvolnyh-polej-postmeta

Comment: @KAGG Design Сортировка работает, главное запихнуть заголовок в цикл перед каждой группой постов

Comment: Какие проблемы вывести заголовок внутри цикла? Ничего непонятно. Покажите желаемую структуру html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код должен быть примерно таким:

```
<?php
global $post;
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'objects',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'       => 'comm_title',
);
$comm = new WP_Query( $args );
$prev_comm_title = '';
if ( $comm->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php
    while ( $comm->have_posts() ) :
        $comm->the_post();
        $comm_title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'comm_title', true );
        if ( $comm_title !== $prev_comm_title ) {
            $prev_comm_title = $comm_title;
            echo esc_html( $comm_title );
        }
        ?>

        <span class="post"><?php the_title(); ?></span>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
?>
```

Получаем для каждого поста значение метаполя comm_title, сравниваем его с предыдущим значением, если не совпадает - выводим comm_title на экран (форматирование оформите так, как вам надо).